# Can a Pokemon have more than one status condition at the same time?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I was playing Omega Ruby over the week and my Gardevoir was paralyzed by Gloom's use of [Stun Spore](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stun_Spore_(move)). Then, the wild Gloom used [Sleep Powder](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sleep_Powder_(move)) and it told me that the move failed. Is this because my Gardevoir was already afflicted with [Paralysis](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Paralysis_(status_condition)) or because of some other factor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Pokémon can only be afflicted by **one non-volatile** status condition at a time.
A non-volatile status condition is a status condition that remains outside of battle and after being switched out.
These are: *Burn*, *Freeze*, *Paralysis*, *Sleep* and *Poison*.

A Pokémon can be affected by **multiple volatile** status conditions at a time.
A volatile status is a status condition that will wear off when a Pokémon is switched out of battle or when a battle is over.
These are: *Confusion*, *Curse*, *Flinch*, *Infatuation*, *Seeding*, *Taunt*...

Source, [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Status_condition).